# Square For Gravity Forms Not Working - Not Returning Error

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, square, gravityforms

Working with Wordpress and Square. I've got Square for Gravity Forms installed and am running on the test APIs. When I submit the form, I get the following error: "There was a problem with your submission. Errors have been highlighted below." It highlights the entire credit card section including zip code.

I have double checked everything three - four times and cannot see anything in the error log, no theme conflicts, and the correct access tokens and IDs are being used.

Where should I search further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. This plugin will not work if the form has multiple pages and the credit card fields are on the final page.